# GIF exports last row of pixels incorrectly

Tags: ios, swift, gif

I am using `CGImageDestinationAddImage` in a swift project to create animated GIF files from photos. This all works fine, except the bottom row of pixels in the final GIF is always the same (these are the pixels from the first photo I added). The photos are all the same size (600x600 pixels).

**I have noticed that this happens on an iPad 2 running iOS 9.3.5, but it works fine on an iPad Pro 12.9" running iOS 10.2. So this may be related to 32-bit vs 64-bit or iOS version.**

Does anyone know whether this is a known issue, or what I'm doing wrong? I've pasted my code below.

```
// Load photos
var photos = [Data]()

for index in 1...5 {
    if let imageDataURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "photo_\(index)", withExtension: "jpg"),
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imageDataURL, options: []) {

        photos.append(data)
    }
}

// Create the GIF

let temporaryDirectory = NSTemporaryDirectory()
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: temporaryDirectory).appendingPathComponent("slideshow.gif")

guard let destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(url as CFURL, kUTTypeGIF, photos.count, nil) else {
    return
}

// Repeat forever by setting the loop count to 0
let gifFileProperties = [kCGImagePropertyGIFLoopCount as String: 0]
let fileProperties = [kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary as String: gifFileProperties]

CGImageDestinationSetProperties(destination, fileProperties as CFDictionary)

// Set the frame delay to 2 seconds
let gifFrameProperties = [kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime as String: 2.0]
let frameProperties = [kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary as String: gifFrameProperties]

for photo in photos {

    if let imageProvider = CGDataProvider(data: photo as CFData),
        let cgimage = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: imageProvider, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: .defaultIntent) {
        CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, cgimage, frameProperties as CFDictionary)
    }
}

guard CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination) else {
    return
}

// Get the gif data.
let gifData = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
```

Comment: What's the point of converting to JPEG first? Use the original images directly, avoid the lossy compression.

Comment: I have updated the code, it still happens when I read the images directly without converting to JPEG first.

Comment: What is exact size pixel dimensions of jpeg you are using? I'm trying to recreate your issue. Just tried with 400 x 400 pixel images and couldn't replicate.

Comment: NVM i was able to replicate with ipad2 simulator and ios 9.3

Comment: I have been using photos of 600x600 pixels (updated the question)